Vscode not importing System.Object or any other library
I am encountering an issue with Visual Studio Code where it is not recognizing inherited files correctly. Initially, I had a problem where, in multiple places, class A inherits from class B, but VS Code kept throwing "can't find B" errors.
I tried running dotnet restore to fix this, but now am facing a different issue. VS Code is reporting that basic types like System.Object are not defined or imported. Here is an example of one of the errors:
error CS0518: Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported

Iv'e already tried restarting, restoring, and so on to no effect.
